# Strange key combination: <CTRL-\><e> (in Cmdline mode)

Tags: key-bindings, command-line

Running `:h ctrl-\` in Vim opens the subsection about the mapping of <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> in Cmdline mode to evaluate an expression and to replace the command line with the result.

Is <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd> used for something in other modes too? (I couldn't find anything about this) Even if it is, why is key sequence to evaluate an expression in Cmdline mode not simply <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd>?  Are there other key mappings starting with <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd> in Cmdline mode?  Will there be problems if I do `cnoremap <C-\> <C-\>e`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:help CTRL-\`<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> will show you all the help topics that contain `CTRL-\`.  As you can see, there are a number of default keybindings that use `CTRL-\`.

As to whether that will cause problems, well that depends on your definition of problem. :) Do you want to be able to use any of those other commands?  If not, then it shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: Indeed, there are two other (strange to use) combinations: `c_CTRL-\ CTRL-N` and `c_CTRL-\ CTRL-G`.